# Comparison between Swift and Objective C in Image Processing

Tags: objective-c, swift, image-processing

I am about to start working on my master project which is processing images that are captured by an iOS application. My supervisor gave me the option to either develop the application with Swift or Objective C. I have searched online about which of them is better in terms of image processing and I still could not determine which one is better. Therefore, what would you suggest?

Comment: You don't really need to decide in advance; mixing and matching is trivial — the vast majority of companies that have adopted Swift within an existing project have done so in a piecemeal fashion. The two work together flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

You can do everything with Swift, that you can do with Objective-C, but Swift offers additional advantages.

Swift has a simpler but more powerful syntax. You only need to maintain single source files, instead of interface/implementation pairs. Swift has better ways of dealing with errors and optional properties. Most importantly, for your image processing app, the compiler will optimize Swift code to run faster than Objective-C.

As with Cocoa objects, any pre-existing Objective-C image processing frameworks you might wish to use, can be called from Swift with no problem — so, you can "mix and match" as desired.

The only reason I can think of why you might wish to choose Objective-C over Swift, would be if time were of the essence and you were already totally up to speed with Objective-C, and had no time to learn Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Any answer to your question will contain a fair amount of *opinion* and you need to weigh up the pros'n'cons yourself and make a decision - there is no right or wrong answer here.

> which of them is better in terms of image processing

Neither. You'll also probably be using existing frameworks a fair amount and writing C-level (as in the language) code and that will work out much the same in either language.

> I am about to start working on my master project

Go with which you are most comfortable with, you want to be able to concentrate on the topic of your Masters and not spend time learning a language/paradigm you are unfamiliar with.

Consider that Swift is still in a state of flux, Swift 3 is expected sometime in 2016 and it will change things - Apple have made it clear that (at least the first versions of) Swift is not yet stable and code may be broken by updates. This doesn't mean you shouldn't use Swift, but if you do try to stick with the same version during your Masters and resist any temptation to upgrade.

HTH, and may your Masters go well.